# Skip first and last line from a pipe delimited file with 26 columns and make it to dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

```
HD|20211210
DT|D-|12/22/2017|12/22/2017 09:41:45.828000|11/01/2017|01/29/2018 14:46:10.666000|1.2|1.2|ABC|ABC|123|123|4554|023|11/01/2017|ACDF|First|0012345||f|ABCD|ABCDEFGH|ABCDEFGH||||
DT|D-|12/25/2017|12/25/2017 09:24:20.202000|12/13/2017|01/29/2018 07:52:23.607000|6.4|6.4|ABC|ABC|123|123|4540|002|12/13/2017|ACDF|First|0012345||f|ABC|ABCDEF|ABCDEFGH||||
TR|0000000002
```

File name is Datafile.Dat. Scala version 2.11

I need to create header Dataframe with the first line but excluding "HD|", Need to create trailer dataframe with the last line but excluding "TR|", and finally need to create actual dataframe by skipping both the first and last line and excluding "DT|" from each line.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have a defined schema for your dataframe (except first and last row).
What you can do is to read that file and seperator will be '|'
and you can enable "DROPMALFORMED" mode.

```
schema = 'define your schema here'
df = spark.read.option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").option("delimiter","|").option("header","true").schema(schema).csv("Datafile.Dat")
```

Another way is to use zipWithIndex.

Comment: Ran the same, but getting below error. `scala> val df = spark.read.csv("Datafile.Dat", sep="|", mode="DROPMALFORMED", schema=dataschema)
<console>:32: error: overloaded method value csv with alternatives:
  (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (csvDataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String, sep: String, mode: String, schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)`

Comment: since you're using scala, no overload for csv function. instead spark.read.option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").option("delimiter","|").option("header",true").load("Datafile.Dat")